# Using LazyColumn inside ComposeView with Fragment happen error

Tags: scroll, scrollable, lazycolumn

1. Activity using fragment to load Compose, and fragment width and height are match_parent
2. Fragment create a `ComposeView`
3. `ComposeView` add a `LazyColumn` like this:

```
class FragmentFavorite : FragmentBase() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent { Fragment() }
        }
    }

    @Preview
    @Composable
    private fun Fragment() {
        ComposePlaygroundTheme {
            LazyColumn(
                Modifier
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            ) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed. One of the common reasons is nesting layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()). If you want to add a header before the list of items please add a header as a separate item() before the main items() inside the LazyColumn scope. There are could be other reasons for this to happen: your ComposeView was added into a LinearLayout with some weight, you applied Modifier.wrapContentSize(unbounded = true) or wrote a custom layout. Please try to remove the source of infinite constraints in the hierarchy above the scrolling container.
    at androidx.compose.foundation.CheckScrollableContainerConstraintsKt.checkScrollableContainerConstraints-K40F9xA(CheckScrollableContainerConstraints.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListKt$rememberLazyListMeasurePolicy$1$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyList.kt:192)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListKt$rememberLazyListMeasurePolicy$1$1.invoke(LazyList.kt:191)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$1$2$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyLayout.kt:71)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$1$2$1.invoke(LazyLayout.kt:69)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:591)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:103)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$2.invoke-3p2s80s(AndroidOverscroll.kt:580)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$2.invoke(AndroidOverscroll.kt:579)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutModifierImpl.measure-3p2s80s(LayoutModifier.kt:285)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:343)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$1.invoke-3p2s80s(AndroidOverscroll.kt:564)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$1.invoke(AndroidOverscroll.kt:563)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutModifierImpl.measure-3p2s80s(LayoutModifier.kt:285)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:343)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:405)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:343)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.ScrollingLayoutModifier.measure-3p2s80s(Scroll.kt:337)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:343)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$2.invoke-3p2s80s(AndroidOverscroll.kt:580)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$2.invoke(AndroidOverscroll.kt:579)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutModifierImpl.measure-3p2s80s(LayoutModifier.kt:285)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:343)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$1.invoke-3p2s80s(AndroidOverscroll.kt:564)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$1.invoke(AndroidOverscroll.kt:563)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutModifierImpl.measure-3p2s80s(LayoutModifier.kt:285)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:343)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:405)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:343)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1077)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1073)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1073)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.access$performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:36)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.remeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:341)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:320)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.RootMeasurePolicy.measure-3p2s80s(RootMeasurePolicy.kt:38)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:103)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1077)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1073)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1073)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.access$performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:36)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.remeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:341)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1135)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.doRemeasure-sdFAvZA(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:307)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureOnly(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:479)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.recurseRemeasure(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:357)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureOnly(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:348)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onMeasure_Original(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:846)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onMeasure(AndroidComposeView.android.kt)
    at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:26358)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26322)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.internalOnMeasure$ui_release(ComposeView.android.kt:300)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onMeasure_Original(ComposeView.android.kt:287)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onMeasure(ComposeView.android.kt)
    at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:26358)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26322)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6981)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:26358)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26322)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6981)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:26358)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26322)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
    at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:26358)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26322)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6981)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:26358)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26322)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:667)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureLayout(RenderSessionImpl.java:258)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:373)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:450)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:122)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:701)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$8(RenderTask.java:848)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:200)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:298)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

LazyColumn can work on ComoseView

Answer (score 0):

LazyColumn has its own way to determine its height and somehow that logic conflicts with the verticalScroll modifier. And usually for vertical scroll modifier to work you should set maxHeight by using sizeIn or heightIn modifiers. But for some reason LazyColumn will throw an error even if you set maxHeight for it.

But you don't need verticalScroll modifier for LazyColumn to work. Just remove the verticalScroll modifier.
If you need to control scroll state just use state parameter like this.

```
  val state = rememberLazyListState()
  LazyColumn(state = state

            ) {

            }
```